# Joining complex sql oracle select queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex query that selects product id values from history and orders.

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM History h ( SELECT .....) LATEST
WHERE h.ProductId = LATEST.ProductID
AND ....
AND IsActive = true;
```

This query is too long, so I could not write all of it. But it returns a table like this:

```
ProdutID
--------
4654654
9879879
5465465
2132188
7894215
....
```

I want to join this product id result another table that containts ProductId column.

```
SELECT * FROM MySecondTable;

ProductID   Color
---------   -----
4654654     red
9879879     blue
5465465     orange
```

How can I join these two query?

Comment: I was expecting some kind of a *trick* here. Obviously, you know how to join tables - as we can see that in the first part of code you posted. So, if you have the MySecondTable, why didn't you simply join it with the rest of them, in the same FROM clause?

Answer (score 0):

CTEs are a really simple way to do such a thing:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t.*, t2.color
from t join
     MySecondTable t2
     on t.ProductId = t2.ProductId;
```

You could also just add the `join` to the `from` clause of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the firts as inner joined  table

```
  SELECT b.* 
  FROM MySecondTable b
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ProductID
      FROM History h ( SELECT .....) LATEST
      WHERE h.ProductId = LATEST.ProductID
      AND ....
      AND IsActive = true;
  ) t on t.ProductID = b.ProductID
```

Comment: MySecondTable contains 2000000 records and inner joined complex select returns 20 record. So this joined query is too long running an unfinalised.

Comment: if you have an  index  on MySecondTable  ProductID  . the query should run fast.